# Adding an if clause inside php function to only display html attribute if parameter equals true

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a wordpress button shortcode and would like to pass in 3 parameters - class, type and then true/false depending on if the link should be external or not. At the moment however I'm not sure how to wrap this attribute inside the function and was wondering if anyone could advise me on how to solve this?

**PHP**

```
function button($atts, $content = null) {
   extract(shortcode_atts(array('link' => '#', 'type' => '', 'external' => 'false'), $atts));
   return '<a href="/'. $link .'" class="btn" ' . if( 'external' == 'true' ) . 'target="_blank"><i class="btn-'. $type .'"></i>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
}
add_shortcode('button', 'button');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep it simple. Do your operation, assign to variable & use it, as below.

```
$target = "_self";
if($external == 'true' ){
   $target = "_blank";
}
return '<a href="/'. $link .'" class="btn"  target="' . $target . '"><i class="btn-'. $type .'"></i>' . do_shortcode($content) . '</a>';
```

Comment: PHP's loose typing is some sort of pain. To keep your code clean, I would recommend sth. like if($external === true)

Comment: @jossif - OP is passing variable as string `"true"`, with your condition it will get failed to match.

Comment: Sure, you are right. My suggestion implies that values meant to be boolean consequentially should be passed as booleans.